# iPhone Backup location in Mac Pro

Tags: itunes, iphone, macbook-pro

I backed up my iPhone using iTunes, the backup location supposed to be:

```
~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/
```

But when I go to Application Support I could not find the folder "MobileSync", where supposed to be then?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed the correct location for iPhone backups.

Make sure you're in the correct Library…

- click onto the Finder, then
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for New Window
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  for Go To…
- Copy/paste `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/` including the tilde ~
- Hit Go

BTW, if you encrypt your backups to preserve login data, passwords etc, then there's nothing human-readable in that folder

Comment: I got only a folder named "acd21eeaa63785158359bd9e35cb3529feeef03c" and there is nothing inside

Comment: It should contain your last backup - if encrypted that will be hundreds if not thousands of items with equally incomprehensible names. I'd be tempted to do another backup & see what happens

Comment: oh yeah I found it, if encrypted, how can I open them?

Comment: Maybe something like http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/42433/ibackup-viewer [untested] freeware & $50 versions

Comment: btw, i bet all the myriad of this type of app will only work once you pay your money - hence I've not tested any of them.

Comment: So how can I backup and should not be encrypted?

Comment: The backups are not meant to be picked apart, they're meant for total restoration in case of disaster. You can do it if they're not encrypted, but you're still not really meant to. Also non-encrypted backups contain no passwords or other secure data, so after a restoration you need to re-enter all that kind of data.